# Adding Custom filter Apache Shiro + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, shiro

I am trying to refactor my Spring MVC xml based project configurations to Spring Boot java based configurations. While setting up shiro configurations as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {

    @Bean
    public Realm realm() {
        JdbcRealm myRealm = new JdbcRealm();
        myRealm.setCredentialsMatcher(sha256Matcher());
        myRealm.setPermissionsLookupEnabled(true);
        myRealm.setSaltStyle(JdbcRealm.SaltStyle.COLUMN);
        return myRealm;
    }

    @Bean
    public HashedCredentialsMatcher sha256Matcher() {
        HashedCredentialsMatcher sha256Matcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
        sha256Matcher.setHashAlgorithmName("SHA-256");
        return sha256Matcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new MemoryConstrainedCacheManager();
    }       

    @Bean
    public Filter jwtv() {
        return new JWTVerifyingFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter ljwtv() {
        return new LimitedAccessJWTVerifyingFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter logout() {
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter();
        logoutFilter.setRedirectUrl("/login.jsp");
        return logoutFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterChainDefinition shiroFilterChainDefinition() {
        DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition chainDefinition = new DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition();

        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/login", "authc");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/logout", "logout");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/my/test/**", "anon");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/my/xyz/**/abc", "ljwtv");            chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/my/xyz/**/mno", "ljwtv");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/my/**", "jwtv");

        return chainDefinition;
    }

}
```

I am encountering the following error:

> Error starting Tomcat context. Exception:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message:
>   Error creating bean with name 'filterShiroFilterRegistrationBean'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/apache/shiro/spring/config/web/autoconfigure/ShiroWebFilterConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean]: Factory
>   method 'filterShiroFilterRegistrationBean' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilterFactoryBean': FactoryBean
>   threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no filter with name
>   'jwtv' to apply to chain [/my/**] in the pool of available Filters. 
>   Ensure a filter with that name/path has first been registered with the
>   addFilter method(s).

The custom filer `JWTVerifyingFilter` is a `@Component` that extends `org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter`. Don't know what I am missing, it all works with the xml configuration. Please Help.

Comment: Can you put together a sample project on GitHub (or somewhere) and i'll try to take a look

Comment: @BrianDemers https://github.com/bibekhadka/demo here it is. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Boot integration doesn't add the Filters from the Spring Context.  (Pre Boot / Java config, this was typically defined in XML, and wasn't an issue).

The workaround is pretty simple though, just add this bean def:

```
@Bean
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean(@Value("#{ @environment['shiro.loginUrl'] ?: '/login.jsp' }") String loginUrl,
                                                     @Value("#{ @environment['shiro.successUrl'] ?: '/' }") String successUrl,
                                                     @Value("#{ @environment['shiro.unauthorizedUrl'] ?: null }") String unauthorizedUrl,
                                                     SecurityManager securityManager,
                                                     ShiroFilterChainDefinition shiroFilterChainDefinition,
                                                     Map<String, Filter> filterMap) {

    ShiroFilterFactoryBean filterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();

    filterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl(loginUrl);
    filterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl(successUrl);
    filterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl(unauthorizedUrl);

    filterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    filterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(shiroFilterChainDefinition.getFilterChainMap());
    filterFactoryBean.setFilters(filterMap);

    return filterFactoryBean;
}
```

I also created a PR to add this back into Shiro (once we add tests).

Update:

I don't think your JSP processing is configured correctly, but the redirect problem is caused by your definition of the logout filter.  That filter is getting processed on every request (by Spring). You would need to use a `FitlerRegistrationBean` mapped to a path instead:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean logout() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter();
    logoutFilter.setRedirectUrl("/login.jsp");
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(logoutFilter);
    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/logout.htm");
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

UPDATE: More fun with automatic filter registration

I think the root of both of these issues is the filters are getting added automatically by Spring, and then also used by Shiro.

If you define the filter bean, and disable it using a `FilterRegistrationBean` Spring does NOT automatically add the filter (IIRC). This means Shiro can manage the filter chain (which is what we want to happen)

Using the following snippet:
```
    @Bean
    public Filter jwtv() {
        return new JWTVerifyingFilter();
    }

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean jwtvFilterRegBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(jwtv());
    filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

```

I was able to trigger your filter when hitting `/`:

`HTTP/1.1 403
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:01:26 GMT
message: NO TOKEN!`

But NOT when hitting `/test`.

For anyone who is trying to implement custom filters like JWT tokenized authorization:
[Sample Project](https://github.com/bibekhadka/shiro-custom-filter)

Comment: Hi @Brian, I tried adding the bean as suggested, which eliminates the runtime exception, but I am not getting the desired output yet. I am not being able to predict the behaviour of any api endpoint. Every endpoint seems to need authentication since I am being redirected to login url. Also the browser says that there are too many redirects. 'anon' seems to do nothing ta an endpoint, weirdly some endpoints are being filtered through my custom implementation. I am getting anxious. Please take a look at endpoint behaviors with the settings.

Comment: Is your loginUrl `/login.jsp` or `/login`? it looks like it your example above uses both, where does the redirect loop send you? That should help narrow it down

Comment: still not able to fix this :(

Comment: push the suggested changes to your GH project and i'll try to take another look

Comment: Hi @Brian, I have pushed the suggested changes. Please have a look.

Comment: I tried the updated code with FilterRegistrationBean which solved multiple redirect problem but still not getting anon controllers to get through. I have pushed the code. Thanks a ton for your time, really appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like a problem with the order in which the filters are executed. Unlike in xml config where there is 'FIRST MATCH WINS policy!', the order in which `DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition` has the chain definitions placed does not seem to  ensure the order in which the filters are applied. It looks like `/api/**` is always executed prior to `/api/test/**` no matter the order. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: You should be able to turn on trace logging to verify this one way or the other.  Can you verify this by setting breakpoints or adding logging in your filters?

Comment: Yes, I have verified the case. I want all endpoints with "/api/**" to be authenticated with my custom filter, named jwtv, except some endpoints like "/api/test/**" which are configured anon. This would easily be achieved in xml config where I placed the "api/test/**" endpoints before the "/api/**" in filterchain defination. But with spring boot all requests with "/api/**" are going through jwtv filter, even "/api/test/**" ones, despite being up the order.

Comment: Hello @Brian, could you please have a look at this issue. The release date is approaching and smth I thought shouldn't take more than couple of hours is getting me stuck for weeks. Sorry to bother you too much but I am getting anxious here. Really appreciate you helping.

Comment: When I run your example I'm prompted to download the JSP, I' guessing the JSP processing is not setup correctly.

Comment: Yes, the authc part is not configured in the project correctly and that is not the part of concern right now. What I am trying to achieve is to have custom filters that validate jwt tokens. Though they remain on the same realm, the authentication happens quite differently. As mentioned earlier, I am now stuck with not being able to configure different filters for the endpoints `/api/**` and `/api/test/**`.

Comment: @BibekKhadka can you create an isolated example to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: the GH project is very close to my actual project. Could you please run the project and visit the url `localhost:8080/api/test/anotherone`. It will show in console output that appkey is missing which shows that `/api/test/**` is being filtered through my custom filter while in the configuration I have mapped `/api/test/**` to `anon` filter. This is happening because I have configured `/api/**` to my custom filter, as you would for the case "Filter everything comming through `/api` except `/api/test/`". The placement of these two chain definations should have been the end of it but...

Comment: Hey @BibekKhadka, I'm not trying to be rude, but it is difficult to debug around known broken code.

Comment: Hi @Brian, I cloned your example project for spring boot shiro integration and added the custom filter that demonstrate the problem. Please have a look: https://github.com/bibekhadka/shiro-custom-filter